# Problems with RGB function on a zoomed picture

Tags: zooming, rgb, raster

I'm working on these sentinel-2 files for an university project and I'm having a problem in this part:

Code

```
 rlist <- list.files(pattern="L1C")
 import <- lapply(rlist, raster)
 vesuvius2017 <- stack(import)
 ext <- c(445000,460000, 4510000, 4525000)
 zoom2017 <- plot(vesuvius2017, ext=ext)  


 plotRGB(zoom2017, r=4, g=3, b=2, stretch="Lin")
```

After the plotRGB I have this error :   ion (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘plotRGB’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

How to solve it? I need to see many different bans to unlight the differences of vegetation cover during the years

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should tag also for the language of your question, and eventually for the special library you are using (if it is not standard in your language). Adding such tags helps relevant people to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 plotRGB(vesuvius2017, r=4, g=3, b=2, stretch="lin",  ext=ext)
```

Or

```
 v <- crop(vesuvius2017, ext)
 plotRGB(v, r=4, g=3, b=2, stretch="lin")
```